# Преобразование типа String в Date

Tags: java, строки, дата

Имеется `String` запись `01:22:00` (*hh.mm.ss*). Нужно сделать ее тип `Date`. Как это можно сделать?

Второе: Имеется `String` запись `Sun Jan 24 23:59:20 SAMT 2016`. Как ее сделать `Date`, но оставить только месяц и год?

Comment: java. Чего-то не сообразил написать про язык

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Код:**

```
1)
String string = "01:22:00";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date;
date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);

2)
String string = "Sun Jan 24 23:59:20 SAMT 2016"; 
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date;
date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

**Подробнее ты можешь почитать в документации Oracle, то есть [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)**

Comment: А можно эту запись реализовать в java.sql.Date?

Comment: @Mitchell Cameron нет конечно. естественно java.util.Date

Comment: так у меня  preparedStatement.setDate() не принимает java.util.Date

Comment: @Mitchell Cameron можно вот так конвертировать
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

Comment: @Mitchell Cameron только в таком формате можно записать дату в БД

Comment: @Mitchell Cameron тот формат не предусмотрен. подробее http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

```
private Date parseDate(String date, String format) throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return formatter.parse(date);
}
```

//Usage

```
Date date = parseDate("19/05/2009", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```