# Из String получить формат Date и прибавить день

Tags: android, дата

У меня есть дата в `TextView` (02.12.2016), мне надо прибавить 1 день.

Я знаю что у класса `Календарь` есть метод `add`, но сначала в календаре надо установить дату в формате `Date`. Вся сложность в том что я не могу из обычного `String` сделать `Date`.

Как из обычного `String` считать дату и прибавить день (месяц, и т.д.)?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485688/177345

Comment: Спасибо, мне нужен был метод parse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "02.12.2016"; 
Date myDate = null; 

try { 
    myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(str); 
} catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
} 

Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance(); 

instance.setTime(myDate); 
instance.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);// прибавляем 1 день к установленной дате    
Date newDate = instance.getTime();// получаем новую дату
```